# JavaScript inheritence and array

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I defined my classes like that:

```
function Employee () {
    this.name = "";
    this.val = new Array();
}

function WorkerBee () {
    this.beeQueen = "lola";

    this.setVal = function(val) {
        this.val.push(val);
    };
}
WorkerBee.prototype = new Employee;


function SalesPerson () {
    this.dept = "development";  
}
SalesPerson.prototype = new WorkerBee;

function Engineer () {
    this.dept = "R&D";
}
Engineer.prototype = new WorkerBee;
```

Problem: all the objects I create share the same val array:

```
var mark = new WorkerBee;
mark.name = "Mark";
mark.setVal('00000')

var louis = new SalesPerson;
louis.name = "Louis";
louis.setVal('11111')

var ricky = new SalesPerson;
ricky.name = "Ricky";
ricky.setVal('33333')

var john = new Engineer;
john.name = "John";
john.setVal('55555');
```

This:

```
html += "<br /><br />Name: " + mark.name;
html += "<br />Val: " + mark.val;

html += "<br /><br />Name: " + louis.name;
html += "<br />Val: " + louis.val;

html += "<br /><br />Name: " + ricky.name;
html += "<br />Val: " + ricky.val;

html += "<br /><br />Name: " + john.name;
html += "<br />Val: " + john.val;
```

displays:

```
Name: Mark
Val: 00000,11111,33333,55555

Name: Louis
Val: 00000,11111,33333,55555

Name: Ricky
Val: 00000,11111,33333,55555

Name: John
Val: 00000,11111,33333,55555
```

I read http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/ and http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/ but I'm still confused!

When I use a string instead of an array this works well (because the reference to the string is overwritten I suppose) but how to do it with array ?

So I can have:

Name: Mark
Val: 00000

Name: Louis
Val: 11111

Name: Ricky
Val: 33333

Name: John
Val: 55555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply) the "parent" constructor in your "inheriting" constructor functions:

```
function WorkerBee () {
    Employee.apply(this);
    /*...*/
}
WorkerBee.prototype = new Employee();
```

Do the same for *all* your "inherited" constructor functions:

```
function SalesPerson () {
    WorkerBee.apply(this);
    /*...*/
}
SalesPerson.prototype = new WorkerBee();

function Engineer () {
    WorkerBee.apply(this);
    /*...*/
}
Engineer.prototype = new WorkerBee();
```

[See the example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDCXF/).

And like @austincheney pointed out, JavaScript has no "classes" - only functions (which are objects), constructors (which are functions) and objects.

---

JavaScript uses [prototypal inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). This means that when you try to access a property (or function) of an object which doesn't exist, it will *delegate* to the prototype object.

Consider:

```
var isaacNewton = {
    name: 'Isaac Newton'
};

function Scientist() {}
Scientist.prototype = isaacNewton;

var neilDeGrasseTyson = new Scientist();

console.log(neilDeGrasseTyson.name);

isaacNewton.name = 'Sir Isaac Newton';

console.log(neilDeGrasseTyson.name);
```

The output here is:

```
Isaac Newton
Sir Isaac Newton
```

Object `neilDeGrasseTyson` hasn't inherited the `name` property. It simply doesn't have one. Since it doesn't have a property `name` when we try to access `name` the `neilDeGrasseTyson`  object will delegate to the prototype object `Scientist.prototype`, and return the value of `Scientist.prototype.name` which is `isaacNewton.name`.

In *your* code, objects `mark`, `louis`, `ricky` and `john` don't have a property `val`. All those calls to `setVal` end up manipulating `WorkerBee.prototype.val` since none of those objects have their own `val` property. By applying the `Employee` constructor to them, you introduce the properties of an `Employee` to them, so they don't have to delegate.

To drive the point home a little more, another solution would have been to put the method `setVal` in `Employee` and give each "inheriting" constructor a `this.val` property: http://jsfiddle.net/FDCXF/1/

Comment: +1 Only other thing I'd probably do would be to put the `setVal` function on `Employee.prototype` since it seems that everything inheriting from Employee will have its own `val` Array. Might as well share the function.

Comment: Ok this works! Thank you for the answer :) But what happens when I don't call .apply internally ? Why is it using a shared variable and why is this the default behavior ? It seems to me like a strange choice for a language to do this!

Comment: @hakulul: Prototypal inheritance is simply an internal chain of object references. When the `val` property is requested from an object created from `Engineer`, it first checks to see if it has that property. If not, it looks at its prototype, which is a `WorkerBee` object. If the `WorkerBee` object doesn't have it, it looks to its prototype, which is an `Employee` object. Because the `Employee` object has that property, that's the value that will be used. As a result, all objects inheriting from that original `new Employee` will all share the same Array.

Comment: Ding! I get it know. When they don't have their own field, JavaScript searches in the prototype chains (so it's shared) but as soon as they have their own field (through .apply) then each have a different one.
Seems pretty simple now that I understand it :)
Thank you for your time  Richard JP Le Guen! It helped a lot. Thank you too RightSaidFred!

Answer (score -2):

1) JavaScript does not have classes.

2) JavaScript only has function scope and not block scope.

3) A variable is only provided scope with the "var" keyword.

Re-engineer your code knowing this and see if you still encounter this problem.

Comment: 1) sorry, but thats just wrong. 2) depends on implementation, ECMAscript specs require block scope, but MSIE ignores this, so many developers avoid using code that relies on block scope.

Comment: @nonchip You might be thinking of a different language.  JavaScript does not have classes at all.  There is some talk of adding classes so that Java developers feel less stupid coming across the wire to JavaScript.  It does not have block scope either, but it will soon.  Block scope will be allowed with the "let" keyword.  Let is already available in the JavaScript 1.7 release which is not tied to any standard.  The standard defining "let" is EcmaScript 6, which is still in development.  As far as I know only Mozilla products fully support "let" at this time.

Comment: @austincheney well, I only use firefox, maybe that's why I'm used to "let". oh, and you're right, there are no "class"es, but you can use functions (using "this" or "prototype") or objects (using functions as object members) somewhat object-oriented, that's what i refer to as classes in javascript...